# Is the Non Profit Starter Pack pre version 3 available as open source?

Tags: apex

As per the documentation here - [Nonprofit Success Pack Documentation](http://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Documentation#!#general) - since version 3, the source code has been open sourced on GitHub:  https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus. This is really cool and helpful.

However, for the Nonprofit Starter Packs that are pre version 3, it seems the code is not open source. I am keen to inspect the classes and triggers of this app here - [Contacts and Organizations for Nonprofit Starter Pack 2](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GLGAEA4), so that I can understand more how this alternative version of person accounts is working.

Having navigated to the installed managed package, I am unable to view the components. The component names of versions pre version 3 don't match those of version 3, and so although the functionality of version 2 is surely in version 3, I can't easily find where this is in the open source version 3.

This isn't a huge problem but I was just wondering if there was the open source code available for the NPSP pre version 3?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all NPSP packages always have been open source! Salesforce.org maintains github repositories for every project at https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation. Each of the five packages that made up NPSP 2 are available there, though you'll need to look through the git `tags` to find the actual 2.0 release.

Here's the Contacts & Orgs package as of 2.1.1: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Contacts_and_Organizations/tree/2.1.1.

Later versions of these packages are all still required to install the Nonprofit Success Pack, but they have been mostly "stripped" and the code moved to the core Cumulus repository.

Answer (score -1):

Version 3 is architected quite differently from how Version 2 was architected to create Households and create the functionality to emulate person accounts and link contacts to other entities. If I'm not mistaken, it actually used Person Accounts while Version 3 does not. I'm not aware of any public repositories of code for Version 2. Your best bet would be to ask this question on The Hub.

Comment: Neither NPSP 2 nor 3 use Person Accounts and neither are recommended. NPSP 3 still continues to support the Individual Bucket and 1-to-1 account models that existed in NPSP 2, and that code is still very much alive and developed.

Comment: @ChristianCarter I know the code for Ver2 is still live and exists. The underlying architecture used for transforming the data into households and other objects changed significantly between Ver 2 and Ver 3. It was also created to be backward compatible. I know that Ver3 does not user Person Accts and even said I might be mistaken on whether Ver2 did. TY for the clarification on that issue.